# Using PDFJS just for text layer and annotation layer

Tags: pdf.js

I want to create a hybrid pdf viewer solutions where the server renders individual pages and they are loaded async into a browser viewer that works like PDFJS (basically, I want to remove the PDFJS rendering engine from the browser).  Is there a way to make the PDFJS lib "pre-render" the PDF and annotations on the server and then have a super light weight version of PDFJS running in the browser to load the assets from the server?

I think I can get the PDFJS lib running on the server to render the image pages.  I think I'm not sure about how to approach the text layers and annotation layers.  The main thing I'm looking for on the annotation layers is the ability to support links within PDFs.